# How to insert inline images in moderncv?

Tags: graphics, moderncv, inline

How could I insert an inline image in the moderncv?

to obtain any similar to

[image]

image panoramic-> http://www.cutudc.com/laborais/images/CONSEL1.PNG

I tried with the typical \begin{figure} .... but no success.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\firstname{\Huge{Manuel}}
\familyname{Dopazo Souto}
\title{\Large{Carpinteiro\newline{}\newline{}Wood worker}}
\address{Rúa dabaixo}{36.000, Pontevedra}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{649.45.74.35}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted                     % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%MICHI%\fax{fax (optional)}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{carpinteiro@carpinteiros.com}
\extrainfo{Data de nacemento: 2 de Xaneiro de 1.492}
\photo[60pt]{example-image-a.jpg}
\nopagenumbers{}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=1.25cm, bottom=1.25cm,right=1.61cm, left=1.61cm}% inner=1cm, outer=0.618\textwidth
\vspace*{-0.56cm}
\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\vspace*{-1.24cm}
\vspace*{-0.18cm}

\section{Formación Académica}

\cventry{2015}{Carpinteria de arriba.}{}{}{\newline{}\scriptsize{Up's wood factory.}}{}{}{\scriptsize{Xan.}}

\cventry{2009--2014}{Carpinteria de abaixo}{}{}{\newline{}\scriptsize{Down wood factory. Galicia.}}{}{}{\scriptsize{Xaquin}} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Habilitaciones por (valided by) %%%% HERE I WANT TO INSERT AN IMAGE %%%%%%
 }
\cventry{Lista de cousas que sabe facer: (List of items)}{Sillas, banquetas, platos, chaveiros, portas, estantes, mobles,...}{}{}{\scriptsize{Galicia}}{}{}{}



\end{document}
%% end of file `template_en.tex'.
```

Comment: `\includegraphics{filename}`? You do not need a `figure` environment to use `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I tried that too, but no success. Here is the error http://www.iestrada.eu/snapshots/snap05164.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to work if you add `\protect` before `\includegraphics`, i.e.

```
\section{Habilitaciones por (valided by) \protect\includegraphics[height=1cm,valign=c]{example-image-16x10}}
```

To use the `valign=c` key, which aligns the image vertically centered on the line, you need to add `\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}` to the preamble.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                   % replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.85]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}  % <-- added

\usepackage{blindtext}
\firstname{\Huge{Manuel}}
\familyname{Dopazo Souto}
\title{\Large{Carpinteiro\newline{}\newline{}Wood worker}}
\address{Rúa dabaixo}{36.000, Pontevedra}    % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\mobile{649.45.74.35}                    % optional, remove the line if not wanted                     % optional, remove the line if not wanted
%MICHI%\fax{fax (optional)}                          % optional, remove the line if not wanted
\email{carpinteiro@carpinteiros.com}
\extrainfo{Data de nacemento: 2 de Xaneiro de 1.492}
\photo[60pt]{example-image-a.jpg}
\nopagenumbers{}

\begin{document}
\newgeometry{top=1.25cm, bottom=1.25cm,right=1.61cm, left=1.61cm}% inner=1cm, outer=0.618\textwidth
\vspace*{-0.56cm}
\maketitle

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\vspace*{-1.24cm}
\vspace*{-0.18cm}

\section{Formación Académica}

\cventry{2015}{Carpinteria de arriba.}{}{}{\newline{}\scriptsize{Up's wood factory.}}{}{}{\scriptsize{Xan.}}

\cventry{2009--2014}{Carpinteria de abaixo}{}{}{\newline{}\scriptsize{Down wood factory. Galicia.}}{}{}{\scriptsize{Xaquin}} 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\section{Habilitaciones por (valided by) \protect\includegraphics[height=1cm,valign=c]{example-image-16x10}}

\cventry{Lista de cousas que sabe facer: (List of items)}{Sillas, banquetas, platos, chaveiros, portas, estantes, mobles,...}{}{}{\scriptsize{Galicia}}{}{}{}


\end{document}
```

[image]